# How to hide warning "The console output contains very long lines (...)" when building apk in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-chipmunk

After I update Android Studio to chipmunk, every time I build the project it gives me this warning. Sometimes it even gives me two times in Run and Build tabs overlapping each other and consuming one click of the mouse to dismiss it, what end up being really annoying.

Is there a way to disable those bubble notifications? Disabling this specific one would be the ideal, but disabling only build notifications should work for me as well.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Warning]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Android Studio Go to *Help | Edit custom propertie***

paste the following line

```
editor.soft.wrap.force.limit=100000
```